# Is this proof about boundedness of Cauchy sequences correct?

Tags: general-topology

### A school exercise reads as follows:

"Show that every Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ is bounded"

### Here is the solution(proof) provided by the lecturer:

"
We show that there is some $r > 0$ and some $x \in X$ such that $\{x_n\} \subseteq B_r(x)$. Since
$\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \geq N$
$$
d(x_n, x_m) < 1
$$
Let
$$
s := \underset{1 \leq i \leq N}{\text{max}} d(x_1, x_i)
$$
Then if $n \leq N$
$$
d(x_n, x_1) \leq s,
$$
while if $n \geq N$, by the triangle inequality,
$$
d(x_n, x_1) \leq d(x_1, x_N) + d(x_N, x_n) < s + 1
$$
It follows that for $r = s+1$, we have $\{x_n\} \subseteq B_r(x_1)$.
"

### Here is my questioning of the validity of this proof:

My issue is with this particular step

> Let
> $$
> s := \underset{1 \leq i \leq N}{\text{max}} d(x_1, x_i)
> $$

It isn't obvious to me that this maximum exists. It seems to me that making the assumption that the maximum exists is *exactly the same* as making the assumption that $\{x_n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. Basically, it seems to me that the proof says the following: "If you assume that $\{x_n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, then $\{x_n\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, i.e circular reasoning. Am I wrong? If so, can someone prove to me why the maximum has to exist?

Comment: There's only finitely many terms.

Comment: Answers have already pointed out why the lecturer's proof works. You can also compare it with the proof that every convergent sequence is bounded. (If you haven't seen a proof of that, even better since you can now try to apply this argument there.)

Comment: You have most likely misread $\max_{1\le i\le N}$ as $\max_{i\ge N}$, which would indeed be problematic because of infinitely many such $i$, or you thought $N$ was the variable the maximum ranges over. However, here $N$ is fixed and for $1\le i\le N$ there are exactly $N$ such indices $i$, so taking the maximum is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum is over finitely many real numbers, and so of course it exists. You are right that it would be circular to take the maximum over all $(i, j)$ pairs, but your professor is taking the maximum only over $N^2$ pairs. This is a fairly common technique in analysis: Somehow reduce an infinitary question to a finitary question.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just realized my mistake:
If $d$ is a metric then for all $x_n, x_m \in X$ it holds that $d( x_n, x_m) < \infty$, which guarantees that the maximum exists. Correct?

Comment: I think you are still missing something: $d(x_n,x_m)$ is a real number; and the maximum of a finite set of real numbers always exists, as one proves by induction on the size of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the $N$ in your expression stated is a fixed integer.
This is from the sentence:

> There is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that ...

Therefore the set
$$ \lbrace d(x_1,x_i) \mid 1 < i \leq N \rbrace $$
is finite.